# How to join two streams with more than one join key

Tags: apache-flink

The following code snippet is copied from javadoc of JoinedStreams

```
val one: DataStream[(String, Int)]  = ...
val two: DataStream[(String, Int)] = ...

val result = one.join(two)
    .where {t => ... }
    .equal {t => ... }
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.of(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .apply(new MyJoinFunction())
```

The two streams are joined based on only one key (computed through `t => ...`), eg, `one.a = two.a`,

I would ask how I could do the join based on more than one key,  eg, one.a = two.a and `one.b = two.b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key selectors can return a Tuple, i.e.,

```
.where {t => (t.a, t.b)}
.equals {t => (t.a, t.b)}
```

Comment: Hi @david so how the following kind of conditions can to be handled with joins/cogroups

`one.a == two.a AND one.b == two.b AND (one.c == two.c OR one.d == two.c )`

Answer (score 1):

By using KeySelector when join, you can generate a tuple to present two keys.